# Working with ASP.NET Cookies collection

Tags: asp.net, cookies

What are the differences between

```
Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value
Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Values
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values is a NameValueCollection enabling you to do:

```
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
MyCookie.Values["Value1"] = "1";
MyCookie.Values["Value2"] = "2";
MyCookie.Values["Value3"] = "3";
MyCookie.Values["Value4"] = "4";
Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
```

Where as value allows you to assign the value of the individual cookie like this:

```
MyCookie.Value = "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie can have more than one value, the second form returns a NameValueCollection
 with multiple values.

A good introduction is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cookies["name"].Value is to check if cookie is null or not. Null is the value if the cookie was never set. Otherwise it gives you the cookie value (no subkeys)
Cookies["name].Values is a subkey=>value pair of the values stored in the cookie.